# Uniqueness of SVM solutions in term of l1 and l2 losses

Tags: machine-learning, classification, mathematical-statistics, svm

I have been reading several articles to find reasonable answers for the difference between L1 (hinge loss)and L2 (squared hinge loss) in solving the primal and dual SVM problems.

I need help to find out answers for these questions:

When the solution of the dual problem is not unique, with respect to L1 loss?
When the solution of the primal problem is not unique, with respect to L1 loss?
Does non-uniqueness affect the performance of classification (in terms of accuracy)?
How can we make the primal and dual solutions unique?
What is the relation between uniqueness solution and the bias b, “ I read that the solution is not unique if and only if b is not unique”?
How do we know the unique value of the bias b?
Why non-uniqueness solution only happens with hinge loss not with squared hinge loss?

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Uniqueness of the SVM Solution](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/1735-uniqueness-of-the-svm-solution.pdf) by Burges and Crisp for most of the answers.

Regarding "accuracy of the solution" - a couple of notes: in the real world we always find an approximate solution, in other words from a purely numerical stand-point we're always within some $\epsilon$ of the training performance of the optimum. Note that in terms of actual performance (i.e., on test data not training data), stochastic methods tend to generalize better, even though they may not reach as "optimal" a value on the training data. Under the assumption that we're solving convex problems then non-uniqueness may actually be a bit more robust since we are likely to find a solution in the interior of the optimal region - rather than for strictly convex problems (with a unique solution) where by definition we can only be in the vicinity for the training data. I don't have any formal proof of this though.

Comment: Really thanks for your clarification. However, I would like to ask, when the support vector points at bound ai=ci, does this mean all ai have the same value of C ?!. For example, if C=10, so all ai points at bound equal to 10.

Comment: Support vectors with $0 < \alpha_i < C$ are all precisely on the margin and have zero classification error. A support vector with $\alpha_i = C$ indicates that the point likely encounters some non-zero classification error (although there is a chance it is still at the margin).